# How to remove handle from faucet without screw

Tags: bathroom

There is no brand name or any other mark on the faucet. I didn't find any set screws. When the plug on the top is removed, I can see the top of the stem. The handle is not attached to the bell part.
Can anybody suggest how to remove the handle so I have access to the leaking stem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When you remove the plug and see the stem, is there an (unoccupied) threaded hole in the stem?

Comment: I have the same faucet and the same issue and I was wondering if you were able to resolve your issue? I am able to remove the handle but not the lower bell part which is impeding my visualization and removal of the cartridge. The bell seems stuck. Were you able to remove yours?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your faucet is similar in design to this [Glacier Bay faucet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Adley-8-in-Widespread-2-Handle-Low-Arc-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Chrome-HD67575W-6001/304367696). The [replacement parts diagram](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/de/de44f425-50b0-47b5-bfbf-20db81eca730.pdf) shows a little "cap" (they call it an "Index") on top of the vertical section which covers a screw. Remove the cap and the screw and everything else should be accessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to use the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar one and the white handle was fixed with a long bolt that went through its length - that just unscrewed...

The other end of the handle is not visible in the picture...

Comment: That gets the white part off, but not the bulk of the handle, which the OP needs off so he can access the stem.

Answer (score 0):

I took apart a faucet set recently where there was an hex allen set screw into the stem on the back side of the handle.  I didn't think to look there for the longest time, but there it was.  Feel around the back of the handle to check.  The end of the handle also screwed off, but that doesn't help.